# .env for jest and nest is not the same

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I want to test a nest api, for that I create one file `.env` and for my dev I create a `.env.development` file.

Which I launch some test with jest my first test uses the good file: `.env` but the second test use the wrong file `.env.development`.

#### How I load the `.env` in nest :

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ConfigService} from './config.service';

@Module({
  providers: [{
    provide: ConfigService,
    useValue: new ConfigService(`.env${process.env.NODE_ENV}`),
  }],
  exports: [ConfigService],
})

export class ConfigModule {}
```

#### How I load the `.env` in jest :

```json
"test:watch": "NODE_ENV='' jest --watch",
```

```json
"jest": {
    "displayName": {
      "name": "API",
      "color": "yellow"
    },
    "verbose": true,
    "runner": "jest-serial-runner",
    "testSequencer": "../src/test/sequencer.jest.js",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node",
    "preset": "@shelf/jest-mongodb",
    "setupFiles": [
      "dotenv/config"  <------------------------| here
    ]
  },
```

#### The test for my `.env` (is ok the right `.env` is loaded)

```
describe('️ tests for env file', () => {
  it('should have a db_user', () => {
    expect(process.env.db_user).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should have a db_pass', () => {
    expect(process.env.db_pass).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should have a db_uri', () => {
    expect(process.env.db_uri).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should have a db_port', () => {
    expect(process.env.db_port).toBeDefined();
  });
  it('should have a db_name', () => {
    expect(process.env.db_name).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

#### The test that loads the wrong `.env` (I put a wrong ip for the db in `.env.development`, so the test failed)

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import {AppModule} from '../app.module';
// remove console.log
console.log = jest.fn();

describe('️ UserController', () => {
  let app;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  /** valid test for create a admin user */
  it('post /users valid test for create a admin user', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/users')
      .send({
        jwt: '',
        firstname: 'admin',
        lastname: 'admin',
        mail: 'admin@gmail.com',
        password: 'test'
      })
      .expect(201);
  });

});
```

Comment: Hey @Hadock Did you found the solution? I am also facing the same issue. I want to use .env.test instead of .env.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a missing `.` after `.env` in this line:

```
new ConfigService(`.env${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
```

However, the extra period is only needed when `process.env.NODE_ENV` contains a value so I would do something like:

```
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV ? `.${process.env.NODE_ENV}` : '';
//...
new ConfigService(`.env${NODE_ENV}`)
```

This way you will either end up with `new ConfigService('.env')` or `new ConfigService('.env.development')`

Answer (score 0):

You can define the path of your file manually.

```
beforeEach(async () => {
    const module: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          envFilePath: ['.env.test'],
          load: [yourConfig],
        }),
      ],
    }).compile()
```

While `yourConfig` is a typical config file

```
export default registerAs('yourConfig', () => ({
  host: process.env.HOST,
}))
```